# How do I generate a random list WITH REPETITION in Python?

Tags: python, random, repeat

I want to generate a random list with repetition and I do not know how it is done, because it always gives me error, I write this:

1. x=rm.sample(range(1001), 2000)
2. print(x)

I want a list of 2000 numbers between 1 and 100

Help me pls.

Comment: If you get an error, you should post it.

Comment: Can you post an [mcve]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the random library and a list comprehension.

```
import random
[random.randint(1,100) for x in range(2000)]
```

If you'd like to print that list, you can assign it a value and print it as you've done in your question.

```
import random
x = [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(2000)]
print x
```

EDIT: Based on OP's comment below: 
If you'd like to remove all values under 50, you can do it while you're generating the initial list and not generate them at all.

```
import random
[random.randint(50,100) for x in range(2000)]
```

Comment: And another question if, I now want to remove from that list those who are over 50, how would?

Thanks and regards

Comment: If you want to remove all numbers under 50, why bother generating them at all?
x = [random.randint(50,100) for x in range(2000)], if you wanted the final resulting array to be a random size, you could also add:
x = [random.randint(50,100) for x in range(random.randint(1000,2000))]